# Does $x^2+ x^4/(3\cdot4) + x^6/(3\cdot4\cdot5\cdot6) + \cdots$ have any compact form?

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series, exponentiation, divergent-series, laurent-series

Is there any compact form for the following series

$$F_1(x) = x^2+ \frac{x^4}{3\cdot4} + \frac{x^6}{3\cdot4\cdot5\cdot6} + \cdots$$
$$F_2(x) = x+ \frac{x^3}{2\cdot3} + \frac{x^5}{2\cdot3\cdot4\cdot5} + \cdots$$
$$F_3(x) = F_2(x) - F_1(x)$$

Comment: Refer to this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_function#Taylor_series_expressions

Comment: another perspective: they all satisfy simple second-order differential equations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$F_2$ is the sum of the odd powers of $x$ divided by factorials, it should remind you of the Taylor development of $e^x$. Indeed, you get the series with only odd terms by combining $e^x$ and $e^{-x}$:
$$F_2(x)=\frac{e^x-e^{-x}}2=\sinh x.$$
This is known as the hyperbolic sine.
Similarly, $F_1$ is the sum of even powers, the hyperbolic cosine, but all factorials are missing the factor $2$, and the constant term is absent.
$$F_1(x)=e^x+e^{-x}-2=2\cosh x-2.$$
By difference,
$$F_3(x)=2-\frac{e^x+3e^{-x}}2.$$

Answer (score 3):

First of all, as yoyo says, these can be solved through differential equations.  For example, if $y=2+F_1(x)$, then we have

$$y''=y,y(0)=2,y'(0)=0$$

However, given both $F_1(x)$ and $F_2(x)$ to work with, we can use $e^x=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n!}$ to see that

$$\frac{F_1(x)}2+F_2(x)+1=e^x$$
$$\frac{F_1(x)}2-F_2(x)+1=e^{-x}$$

From here, it's simple algebra.

Answer (score 1):

Yes,

$F_1(x) = 2(\cosh x - 1)$;

$F_2(x) = \sinh x$.

(see [Taylor series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series#List_of_Maclaurin_series_of_some_common_functions)).

Comment: Many thanks, can you tell what happens if x goes to $\infty$?

Comment: Well, if you observe the limit as $x\to\infty$, you can see what will happen

Comment: Then $F_1(x), F_2(x), F_3(x) \rightarrow +\infty$, if $x \to +\infty$.

Comment: Asymptotic: $~~~\lim\limits_{x\to +\infty} \dfrac{F_1(x)}{e^x}=1$, $~~~\lim\limits_{x\to +\infty} \dfrac{F_2(x)}{e^x}=\dfrac{1}{2}$, $~~~\lim\limits_{x\to +\infty} \dfrac{F_3(x)}{e^x}=-\dfrac{1}{2}$.

Comment: oops, $F_3(x)\rightarrow - \infty$, if $x\to + \infty$.